# running glmer with factors that have more than 2 levels?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am trying to run the `glmer()` function on results from an experiment I conducted. The dependent variable, `FirstResponseKey`, is a binomial variable (0\1). The model looks like this:

```
mflicker <- glmer(FirstResponseAccuracy ~ 1 + Aware*lag*SameLocation + (1|Subject),
                  family = binomial(link="logit"), data = data_flicker)
summary(mflicker)
meansFlicker <- effect("Aware*lag*SameLocation", mflicker) 
summary(meansFlicker)
```

All fixed variables are factors, `Aware` and `SameLocation` have 2 levels, while `leg` have 3 level- which created unexpected problems. The problem is that the output gives me p-values for each level of the factor `lag` separately, like this:

```
    Fixed effects:
                            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)                0.7143714  0.2636160   2.710  0.00673 **
Aware1                    -0.4173583  0.1577041  -2.647  0.00813 **
lag3                      -0.0685717  0.1802532  -0.380  0.70363   
lag7                      -0.3193594  0.1799608  -1.775  0.07596 . 
SameLocation1              0.0937725  0.1797897   0.522  0.60197   
Aware1:lag3                0.0165164  0.2148904   0.077  0.93874   
Aware1:lag7                0.6276651  0.2154301   2.914  0.00357 **
Aware1:SameLocation1       0.3485323  0.2170429   1.606  0.10831   
lag3:SameLocation1        -0.1404866  0.2581919  -0.544  0.58636   
lag7:SameLocation1        -0.0004234  0.2615045  -0.002  0.99871   
Aware1:lag3:SameLocation1 -0.5017417  0.3080803  -1.629  0.10340   
Aware1:lag7:SameLocation1 -0.4578527  0.3115991  -1.469  0.14173
```

I don't know how to interpret these results. I want the main effect and interactions of `lag` as a whole, not by levels.

I tried scaling and centering the `lag` factor, and then the model indeed gives me the effect of lag across levels - but then I have a different problem: when I try to print out the mean of each condition, I get 5 different levels of `lag` although there are supposed to be only 3!

Theoretically, I can regard `lag` both as a factor or as an ordinal variable - but I can't make either of these options work.

What should I do?

Edit-
Here is a reproducible example.The remaining issue is 1) I don't know how to perform pairwise comparisons between every two simple conditions. I tried to follow other posts but it didnt work with 3 ID variables. 2)Even though I get many significant effects, the SE are extremely high- about 5 times higher compared to when I use LME instead of GLM. (see my question in this post: [strangely large se when using glm compared to lme](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265251/strangely-large-se-when-using-glm-compared-to-lme))

```
      data_Report <-  structure(list(lag = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L,              
        2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
        3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
      3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L,     
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "3", "7"), class = "factor"), Aware =           structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    SameLocation = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    Subject = c(102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 
    102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 
    102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 
    102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 
    102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 
    102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 
    102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 
    102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 
    102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 
    102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 
    102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 
    102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 
    102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 
    102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 
    103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 
    103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 
    103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 
    103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 
    103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 
    103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 
    103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 
    103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 
    103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 
    103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 
    103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 
    103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 
    103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 
    103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 
    106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 
    106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 
    106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 
    106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 
    106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 
    106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 
    106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 
    106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 
    106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 
    106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 
    106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 
    106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 
    106L, 106L, 106L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 
    108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 
    108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 
    108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 
    108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 
    108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 
    108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 
    108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 
    108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 
    108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 
    108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 
    108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 
    108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 
    108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 
    108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
    115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
    115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
    115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
    115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
    115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
    115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
    115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
    115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
    115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
    115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
    115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
    115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
    115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
    115L, 115L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 
    118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 
    118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 
    118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 
    118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 
    118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 
    118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 
    118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 
    118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 
    118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 
    118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 
    118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L), FirstResponseAccuracy = c(1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("lag", 
"Aware", "SameLocation", "Subject", "FirstResponseAccuracy"), row.names = c(3L, 
6L, 7L, 10L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 28L, 30L, 32L, 39L, 46L, 53L, 
54L, 58L, 65L, 66L, 72L, 76L, 78L, 88L, 89L, 91L, 94L, 103L, 
104L, 118L, 128L, 130L, 132L, 135L, 136L, 143L, 148L, 152L, 153L, 
156L, 161L, 164L, 165L, 169L, 172L, 183L, 185L, 186L, 188L, 190L, 
199L, 200L, 203L, 206L, 207L, 213L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 220L, 225L, 
229L, 243L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 249L, 250L, 252L, 253L, 255L, 258L, 
259L, 261L, 262L, 265L, 266L, 268L, 270L, 271L, 279L, 281L, 282L, 
292L, 298L, 299L, 303L, 305L, 308L, 311L, 312L, 315L, 319L, 321L, 
327L, 333L, 335L, 337L, 339L, 340L, 342L, 348L, 349L, 350L, 354L, 
371L, 373L, 374L, 375L, 376L, 380L, 383L, 384L, 387L, 389L, 390L, 
392L, 396L, 398L, 400L, 406L, 408L, 415L, 419L, 421L, 422L, 426L, 
431L, 437L, 443L, 444L, 446L, 449L, 454L, 460L, 471L, 477L, 478L, 
484L, 485L, 493L, 494L, 501L, 502L, 503L, 505L, 506L, 507L, 512L, 
514L, 525L, 528L, 530L, 532L, 536L, 543L, 544L, 551L, 552L, 561L, 
565L, 566L, 567L, 569L, 570L, 572L, 576L, 578L, 583L, 584L, 587L, 
588L, 590L, 591L, 594L, 596L, 604L, 608L, 609L, 613L, 617L, 618L, 
626L, 628L, 635L, 642L, 645L, 647L, 657L, 658L, 659L, 660L, 663L, 
664L, 667L, 671L, 672L, 676L, 677L, 689L, 690L, 695L, 703L, 705L, 
708L, 712L, 714L, 715L, 716L, 719L, 724L, 729L, 730L, 731L, 734L, 
735L, 737L, 738L, 741L, 742L, 749L, 752L, 754L, 755L, 757L, 758L, 
762L, 763L, 773L, 777L, 784L, 787L, 800L, 810L, 812L, 819L, 820L, 
821L, 828L, 831L, 836L, 838L, 839L, 841L, 842L, 847L, 857L, 858L, 
862L, 864L, 869L, 873L, 875L, 878L, 882L, 885L, 886L, 887L, 893L, 
895L, 896L, 902L, 903L, 908L, 910L, 912L, 924L, 928L, 929L, 930L, 
938L, 947L, 951L, 954L, 1910L, 1914L, 1928L, 1929L, 1930L, 1934L, 
1936L, 1937L, 1948L, 1951L, 1952L, 1959L, 1968L, 1969L, 1974L, 
1975L, 1976L, 1979L, 1985L, 1991L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1998L, 
1999L, 2002L, 2010L, 2016L, 2018L, 2020L, 2028L, 2033L, 2043L, 
2051L, 2057L, 2062L, 2064L, 2066L, 2068L, 2079L, 2081L, 2083L, 
2084L, 2090L, 2092L, 2098L, 2101L, 2104L, 2107L, 2112L, 2113L, 
2114L, 2115L, 2116L, 2120L, 2122L, 2123L, 2126L, 2129L, 2139L, 
2143L, 2145L, 2156L, 2161L, 2166L, 2172L, 2173L, 2174L, 2175L, 
2178L, 2187L, 2188L, 2193L, 2201L, 2207L, 2210L, 2218L, 2219L, 
2223L, 2224L, 2227L, 2228L, 2230L, 2235L, 2237L, 2239L, 2242L, 
2244L, 2249L, 2266L, 2269L, 2271L, 2273L, 2274L, 2275L, 2276L, 
2277L, 2278L, 2282L, 2283L, 2291L, 2297L, 2301L, 2307L, 2309L, 
2311L, 2314L, 2317L, 2323L, 2325L, 2329L, 2330L, 2335L, 2337L, 
2341L, 2344L, 2349L, 2351L, 2353L, 2354L, 2357L, 2360L, 2364L, 
2367L, 2370L, 2371L, 2375L, 2376L, 2383L, 2867L, 2878L, 2881L, 
2883L, 2884L, 2885L, 2886L, 2891L, 2893L, 2899L, 2900L, 2901L, 
2907L, 2913L, 2920L, 2921L, 2926L, 2929L, 2932L, 2933L, 2936L, 
2937L, 2938L, 2941L, 2946L, 2947L, 2952L, 2953L, 2954L, 2957L, 
2964L, 2966L, 2972L, 2975L, 2979L, 2984L, 2988L, 2989L, 2990L, 
2992L, 2994L, 2997L, 3000L, 3001L, 3007L, 3015L, 3016L, 3017L, 
3018L, 3019L, 3024L, 3031L, 3038L, 3040L, 3042L, 3049L, 3054L, 
3055L, 3065L, 3071L, 3072L, 3075L, 3076L, 3082L, 3088L, 3090L, 
3098L, 3105L, 3107L, 3108L, 3111L, 3117L, 3119L, 3121L, 3128L, 
3130L, 3131L, 3136L, 3140L, 3142L, 3148L, 3149L, 3153L, 3156L, 
3157L, 3159L, 3163L, 3166L, 3169L, 3171L, 3175L, 3179L, 3180L, 
3182L, 3183L, 3185L, 3190L, 3196L, 3197L, 3200L, 3202L, 3203L, 
3204L, 3208L, 3210L, 3212L, 3217L, 3221L, 3222L, 3223L, 3227L, 
3231L, 3235L, 3239L, 3242L, 3245L, 3246L, 3247L, 3248L, 3249L, 
3250L, 3252L, 3260L, 3276L, 3277L, 3278L, 3283L, 3285L, 3290L, 
3291L, 3292L, 3294L, 3295L, 3297L, 3303L, 3308L, 3310L, 3315L, 
3316L, 3317L, 3319L, 3329L, 6205L, 6215L, 6216L, 6217L, 6219L, 
6221L, 6227L, 6232L, 6234L, 6235L, 6242L, 6243L, 6244L, 6245L, 
6246L, 6247L, 6249L, 6250L, 6259L, 6260L, 6262L, 6265L, 6266L, 
6270L, 6274L, 6275L, 6278L, 6282L, 6283L, 6284L, 6286L, 6290L, 
6291L, 6294L, 6295L, 6302L, 6306L, 6307L, 6312L, 6318L, 6327L, 
6333L, 6334L, 6336L, 6339L, 6345L, 6351L, 6352L, 6365L, 6368L, 
6369L, 6371L, 6375L, 6381L, 6382L, 6384L, 6386L, 6388L, 6393L, 
6394L, 6395L, 6400L, 6404L, 6407L, 6414L, 6417L, 6418L, 6421L, 
6422L, 6426L, 6431L, 6432L, 6436L, 6438L, 6439L, 6440L, 6456L, 
6457L, 6458L, 6461L, 6463L, 6467L, 6475L, 6480L, 6486L, 6489L, 
6492L, 6493L, 6494L, 6498L, 6503L, 6505L, 6509L, 6510L, 6514L, 
6518L, 6523L, 6526L, 6529L, 6535L, 6538L, 6539L, 6540L, 6546L, 
6554L, 6558L, 6559L, 6560L, 6562L, 6566L, 6569L, 6571L, 6573L, 
6579L, 6583L, 6584L, 6588L, 6600L, 6604L, 6605L, 6610L, 6612L, 
6618L, 6619L, 6621L, 6622L, 6628L, 6631L, 6636L, 6637L, 6640L, 
6643L, 6644L, 6653L, 6668L, 6670L, 6678L, 7644L, 7650L, 7656L, 
7657L, 7662L, 7664L, 7665L, 7666L, 7667L, 7670L, 7671L, 7676L, 
7677L, 7680L, 7682L, 7683L, 7691L, 7692L, 7697L, 7707L, 7711L, 
7713L, 7715L, 7717L, 7723L, 7725L, 7728L, 7731L, 7732L, 7736L, 
7742L, 7749L, 7760L, 7762L, 7771L, 7772L, 7774L, 7775L, 7776L, 
7777L, 7782L, 7794L, 7797L, 7801L, 7803L, 7808L, 7810L, 7812L, 
7813L, 7816L, 7819L, 7821L, 7827L, 7830L, 7831L, 7834L, 7839L, 
7841L, 7843L, 7851L, 7853L, 7857L, 7864L, 7869L, 7879L, 7884L, 
7897L, 7902L, 7904L, 7905L, 7911L, 7912L, 7913L, 7915L, 7919L, 
7922L, 7926L, 7932L, 7933L, 7937L, 7939L, 7947L, 7954L, 7957L, 
7959L, 7962L, 7968L, 7969L, 7974L, 7980L, 7984L, 7988L, 7992L, 
7995L, 7996L, 8031L, 8033L, 8036L, 8038L, 8044L, 8049L, 8058L, 
8060L, 8063L, 8066L, 8077L, 8079L, 8080L, 8092L, 8093L, 8098L, 
8100L, 8107L, 8109L), class = "data.frame")      


mm=glmer(FirstResponseAccuracy ~ 1 + lag + Aware + SameLocation+ lag:Aware + lag:SameLocation + Aware:SameLocation + lag:Aware:SameLocation + (1|Subject), family = binomial(link="logit"), data = data_Report)  
#this summary function doesnt work well in glm when using variables with 3 levels..  
summary(mm)  
#this anova does not provide p values  
anova(mm)  
#this Anova provide p values  
####install.packages("car")  
library(car)  
car::recode  
Anova(mm)  

#what is the mean and se in each condition? SE are ridiculously high!!(and much #much smaller when I use lme...)  
NoRe <- effect("lag:Aware:SameLocation",se = TRUE, mm)   
MeansNoRe <- as.data.frame(NoRe)  
MeansNoRe  

#pairwise comparisons???  `
```

Comment: could you try whether: <code>glmer(FirstResponseAccuracy ~ 1 + lag + Aware + SameLocation+ lag:Aware + lag:SameLocation + lag:Aware:SameLocation + (1|Subject), family = binomial(link="logit"), data = data_flicker)</code> gives you what you want?

Comment: Would you be happy with the output of `anova(mflicker)`?

Comment: The first part of your suggestion did not solve the problem in the output (still separate effects for each level of lag).
The output of anova(mflicker) looks great but lacks p values..

Comment: Load the lmerTest package and try again.

Comment: Here is a reproducible example:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see an ANOVA-type table of the model fit, use the `mixed()` function of the `afex` package:

```
library(afex) 
mixed(FirstResponseAccuracy ~ 1 + Aware*lag*SameLocation + (1|Subject),
      family = binomial(link="logit"), data = data_flicker, method="PB")
```

*Note*: You have the specify the `method` how to calculate the p-values. In this case, I chose `method="PB"`, which stands for parametric bootstrap. This may not be ideal in your scenario and it could take some time to compute. You need to read the **Details** section in the help file `?mixed`.

To get the means, I would use the `lsmeans()` function from the `lsmeans` package, for example:

```
library(lsmeans)
lsmeans(mflicker, c("Aware","lag","SameLocation"))
```

You can also use the `lsmeans()` function to test for significant differences between the levels of your factors, for example:

```
lsmeans(mflicker, pairwise ~ Aware*lag*SameLocation)
```

Same here, have a look at the `lsmeans` [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsmeans/vignettes/using-lsmeans.pdf).

**EDIT:**

Using your reproducible example everything works fine as outlined above, except for the `Model failed to converge` warning. As per this thread [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97834/warning-messages-from-mixed-model-glmer), add `glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000))` to your model to increase the number of iterations and the warning is gone:

```
library(lme4)
mm.new = glmer(FirstResponseAccuracy ~ 1 + lag + Aware + SameLocation + lag:Aware +
               lag:SameLocation + Aware:SameLocation + lag:Aware:SameLocation + 
               (1|Subject), family = binomial(link="logit"), data = data_Report,
               glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)))
```

Check `summary(mm.new)` for random and fixed effects. To get the ANOVA-type table you wanted, use the `mixed()` function (`afex` package) or the `Anova()` function (`car` package). For lsmeans, SEs and all pairwise comparisons, use the `lsmeans()` function (`lsmeans` package) as suggested above.

Comment: The mixed function indeed sounds like what I need, but when I use "PB" for p values, it gets stuck on calculating the p values (more than 12 hours and still calculating..)
According to the documentation of this function, the only other method relevant is "KR", but this one gives an error msg saying:
 no applicable method for 'KRmodcomp' applied to an object of class "c('glmerMod', 'merMod')"

do u have an idea why? I find it hard to believe that there is no way to get p values in glmer for multilevel variables..

Comment: @EyalAlefOphir How many levels of random effects (Subjects) do you have? In any case you could try `method=LRT` to see whether that works. You could also try `car::Anova(mflicker)`. Does that work?

Comment: I have 16 subjects. 
lsmeans does not work, it gives me the following msg: "Error in lsmeansLT(mflicker, c("Aware", "lag", "SameLocation")) :  The model is not linear mixed effects model "   - the model was created with glmer, and I indeed used the car : : Anova functionm and it worked well.

Only thing missing now is the pairwise comparisons

Comment: @EyalAlefOphir It's hard to troubleshoot without a [reproducible example](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Reproducibility.html)... I just tried it again with some of my own data and everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I edited the question and provided a reproducible example

Comment: Thanks a lot! Two problems remain:
1) lsmeans does not work with glm objects, instead I am using the effects package. 
It gives me huge SEs, which don't make sense. (e.g: the difference between 2 conditions is 10% and significant, but the SE is 25%... almost as if it gives SD instead of SE).

2. Since the lsmeans doesnt work with glm, I used glht (multcomp package) on a model created for the interaction variable : _comp.coa<- glht(mm1, linfct=mcp(LagLocAwa="Tukey"))_
Is there a way to do it without the Tukey correction? (these are planned comparisons)

Comment: @EyalAlefOphir Sorry I don't know off the top of my head why there is the discrepancy between the SEs from the different models. But since you have repeated measurements on subjects, why are you not going for the `glmer` model? Both the `lsmeans` and `multcomp` packages allow for contrast testing.  I've never done it though. Check the documentations for these packages for instructions on how to do it. I am sure there are some examples that could help you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that glmer is performing a regression analysis (as it is meant to do) when you want an ANOVA framework. You would have the same problem if you were running lm on cross-sectional data. You could figure out the contrast coding, or...

With your glmer model fit, I think a good approach would be to use `Anova` in the [car](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/car.pdf) package to run the ANOVA. You can the follow-up with post-hoc analyses using the [multcomp package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcomp/multcomp.pdf); or you can use [phia](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/phia/phia.pdf) to focus on interactions.

This [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5250/multiple-comparisons-on-a-mixed-effects-model) might help as well.